# How to display from category 17 only one post?

Tags: wordpress

I have some code that I was trying to display only one post from the category 17. But I can't it. Anybody have any idea? my code is below. I have tried it but show all post of category 17. I want to show only one post from cat 17.

```
              <?php
                if(have_posts()):?>
              <?php while(have_posts()):?>
               <?php the_post();?>
                <?php
                $post = $wp_query->post;
                if ( in_category( '17' ) ) {
                ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <div class="car_box shadow left">
                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <!--<img src="images/car2.png" alt="PREMIUM CARS" align="middle"/>-->
                    <?php
                    // Post Image.

                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

                    the_post_thumbnail();
                    }
                    else {
                    echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) .         '/images/thumbnail-default.jpg" />';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <p>BMW 7 Series or simillar</p>
                    <div class="desc left">
                        <div class="passenger left">
                        4
                        </div>
                        <div class="suitcase left">
                        3
                        </div>
                        <div class="doors left">
                        5
                        </div>
                        <div class="gear left">
                        Auto
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="viewmore left">View More</a>
                </div>
                </a>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php endwhile;?>
              <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: can you give more context of what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `break;` in the loop after you've shown your first found post, that would be before you close the inner if statement.

Comment: Great answer. it works as well. one problem the old one come first. need the latest one first. can recheck please

Comment: In order to keep most of your current code intact, you could do this via setting the "current_post" property in $wp_query object. Add these lines right before the_post() call: `global $wp_query; $wp_query->current_post = $wp_query->post_count - 2;`